# Android: Clicking on an image to switch to another image

Tags: android

What's a good way, both layout- and codewise, to accomplish the following:

- Display one or more clickable images on the screen.
- By default, the images are default images (duh)
- When clicking on them, they change to a specified image
- When clicking again, the change back to the default image

I cannot set all the images in the xml layout file(s), since I must be able to programatically set and change the images when clicking, and keep a record of the images on display etc.

In case anyone wonders: Yes, this is supposed to be a simple "memory" game, where I show x images, and click on two of them to display them, and give a result if they're identical.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use ImageSwitcher, as the view, and setOnClickListener on the ImageSwitcher, to apply image changes on click action.

Comment: I can't really find any good examples of using imageswitcher without gallery, which seems to be the primary use for it? To begin with, I just want to display ONE image on the screen, and decide programatically which image. Then I want to display another image in its place, set programatically, when the image is clicked.